# How can I logged in with the same account in 2 different PHP (Codeigniter) local application?

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, session

I've an issue that I built 2 different applications in localhost with PHP (Codeigniter), but I can logged in with the same account (My apps connect with different database). If I Logged out one of the application, so the other one is also logged out. Is that normal? If it's not, Why just this happened and how to fix it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your code when you logout?